# Hi, I'm getting started with PHP and I'm stuck with a beginner's error

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="site.php" method="get">
 Name: <input type="text" name="username">
 <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
echo $_GET["username"]
 ?>
```

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\phplessons\index.php on line 26

After filling in the answer will be displayed.
Object was not found!

Thank you in advance for every answer.

Comment: You have to first test that the form has been submitted. The first time the page loads, it wont have been submitted and $_GET['userbame''] will not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable will be created only after submitting the form. That is why in the code you need to make a check-up and only then show that variable. Try like this:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['username'])){
       echo $_GET["username"];
   }

?>
```

Comment: Do or Do Not, there is no "Try" padawan. A **good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated answer, added explanation.

Comment: Proper bracing and closing should be used also.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner also added that.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov I noticed ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Now it doesn't report me error, but after completing the form. It will give me an error Object not found!
Error 404
Could this be a bug in my localhost?

Comment: @estrower it is because your form is sending site.php. Try to change form action from site.php to "/"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. @ElmanHuseynov

Comment: @estrower you are welcome. Please tick green my answer if it solves your issue.